# How do you make a letter in a circle transparent to the background? (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape, transparency, background

Say you have a circle, and a letter (X), on top of that circle. The circle is black, the background is white, and you want the X to be transparent. HOWEVER, you want the X (or the area where the X occupies) to be transparent to the white background, not the black.

What is this called, and how is it accomplished?

Comment: I would call this "punching out" the lettering

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, you want the X to be totally transparent:

1. Use *Path → Object to Path* on both, the circle and the X.
2. Select the X and then the circle (order matters).
3. Use *Path → Difference.*

Comment: *Path > Difference* also works on Objects. No need to transform to a Path. Also then, selection order will not matter.